# What is the difference between <link> and <script> when using jQuery .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendto

When I do this:

```
$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>');
```

then script.css is loaded and executed, and is available for use immediately.

But when I do this:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="sheet.css" />');
```

then sheet.css is not loaded. However when I look at the generated source, the line in question *has* been added to the  object.

Apparently scripts and style sheets are being treated differently by the browser.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

For link element, specify the source of external stylesheet in `href` attribute. You need to update your code from

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="sheet.css" />');
```

to

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css" />');
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious to me!